# How to get available WiFi list in IOS in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am creating a hybrid application where I'm scanning available WI-fi list and trying to connect it via app. To achieve it in android native I'm using hotspot plugin which is working perfectly fine but it is not available for IOS. Can any one suggest me any cordova plugin which I can use to get WI-fi List and to connect via SSID and password in Ios? I will be grateful if any one will provide some sample codes.

Comment: Try WifiWizard2 https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2

Comment: Do you have any sample codes for it?

Answer (score 0):

iOS has limited functionality as Apple's WifiManager equivalent is only available as a private API. Any app that used these features would not be allowed on the app store.
Connect/Disconnect only works for iOS11+

Comment: Can you share me code how to connect and disconnect WiFi ? it will be helpful.